# Search query by specific section with matrix 'entries' type field?

Tags: entries, search, elementquery

I need help with the search query. I have a structure:
Page (entryType "structure") -> Matrix (fieldType "matrix") -> Collections ("blockType") -> Collections (fieldType many related "entries");

These "Collections" entries have text fields. The search query didn't retrieve the parent element "Page" by these nested fields. In settings "Use this field’s values as search keywords" checked on these fields.

```
{% set results  = craft
    .entries()
    .section(sections)
    .search(searchQuery)
    .status('live')
    .with(['banner', 'elements', 'singleBanner'])
    .orderBy('score')
    .all() 
%}
```

[image]

Thank for any help :)